# Query to find average stock ... with a twist

Tags: sql, postgresql

We are trying to calculate average stock from a movements table in a single sql sentence.

As far as we are, no problem with what we thought was a standard approach, instead of adding up the daily stock and divide by the number of days, as we don’t have daily stock, we simply add (movements*remaining days) :

```
select sum(quantity*(END_DATE-move_date))/(END_DATE-START_DATE)
from move_table
where move_date<=END_DATE
```

This is a simplified example, in real life we already take care of the initial stock at the starting date. Let’s say there are no movements prior to start_date.
Quantity sign depends on move type (sale, purchase, inventory, etc).
Of course this is done grouping by product, warehouse, ... but you get the idea.
It works as expected and the calculus is fine.

But (there is always a “but”), our customer doesn’t like accounting days when there is no stock (all stock sold out). So, he doesnt like

Sum of (daily_stock) / number_of_days (which is what we calculate using a diferent math)

Instead, he would like

```
Sum of (daily stock) / number_of_days_in_which_stock_is_not_zero
```

For sure we can do this in any programming language without much effort, but I was wondering how to do it using plain sql ... and wasn’t able to come up with a solution.

Any suggestion?

Comment: well if you already calculate the number_of_days why don't you just add `number_of_day != 0` in the where clause? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: bouletta, we don't calculate number-of-days at all ... see my sql, we just add MOVES, not real stock.

Comment: a_horse_with-no_name We are using Postgres

Comment: In order to answer this question you need to know how to calculate "number_of_days_in_which_stock_is_not_zero"

Comment: Hogan I'm just trying to find a math equivalent to avoid that. Our actual sql doesn't calculate daily_stock but is able to calculate an equivalent for sum(daily_stock)/number_of_days ... and was wondering if something similar could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a new table called something like Stock_EndOfDay_History that has the following columns.

- stock#
- date
- stock_count_eod

This table would get a new row for each stock item at the start of a new day for the prior day. Rows could then be purged from this table once the applicable date value went outside the date window of interest.

To get the "number_of_days_in_which_stock_is_not_zero", use this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Not_Zero_Stock_Days' FROM Stock_EndOfDay_History
WHERE stock# = <stock#_value> 
AND <date_window_clause>
```

Other approaches might attempt to just add a new column to the existing stock table to maintain a cumulative sum of the " number_of_days_in_which_stock_is_not_zero". But inevitably, questions will be asked as to how did the non-zero stock days count get calculated? Using this new table approach will address those questions better than the new column approach.

Comment: Yes JohnH, sure this works. We cannot build the table on the fly because it would take hours, and we don't want to change the stock managing system to add it in the regular processs. I guess there is no math solution to do it using plain sql, so we will do it in a program reading the rows and calculating the cumulative daily stock. Thanks